# RN error: BTPayPalDriver_Internal.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build My RN project after I deleted the `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` and re-install it again, because I had a different issue, and now I face this error[image]

I tried to install `react-native-braintree` I thought it might fix it, but it didn't.

anyclue how to solve this problem or maybe solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution is :**

I install it [@thang2162/react-native-braintree-dropin-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thang2162/react-native-braintree-dropin-ui), then `cd ios && pod install` and it fixed to me